# Is there a general way to find what $Aut(C_n)$ Is Isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm asked to describe $Aut(C_{21}),Aut(C_{24})...$ as a product of cyclic groups  - but I'm wondering is there a general way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

An automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is uniquely determined by the image of $1$ (generator), and this one as to be a generator, hence an invertible element.

Hence, you get a bijection $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$, which is in fact a group isomorphism. In some cases (for example when $n$ is prime) then the group is cyclic, but not always, like for example when $n=8$.

Comment: sorry what is the notation $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @automobile1 see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n there you also find an explict description of the structure in all cases.